# Facebook sdk php login error

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, token

from today I have a problem with facebook login on my web site. The error is

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

I didn't changed anything. 
I use open graph v2.6 and my call is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name
```

I'm using php 5.6 Codeigniter 2

Thank you for your help

Comment: I found the solution.
In facebook_base.php  the function parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);  return a wrong parameter. If you change this function with this one  json_decode($access_token_response, true);  it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add access token in your call.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name&access_token={access_token}

You can get your access token by visiting:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/